# Search for more than one string in a field using elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am looking for ways to use `elasticsearch_dsl` to query for multiple strings on a single field.
When I try using wildcard option, it just lists last string found

For example, I need to look for following strings in field called `cars_model`

```
“honda_accord”
“honda_crv”
“honda_civic” … etc
```

So the query I am forming is

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
client = Elasticsearch([{'host': MY_HOST, 'port': MY_PORT, 'timeout': TIME_OUT}])

s = Search(using=client,index=“myIndex”).query("wildcard",cars_model=“honda*”).execute()
```

Here, Its returning only listing for “honda_crv” , which I am assuming last  data.

I’ve tried using following options after doing some research

```
body = {'query_string': {'query': ‘honda*’, 'default_operator': 'or', 'analyze_wildcard': True}}
s = Search(using=client, index=“myIndex”).query(body).execute()
```

Even tried `multi_match` option which still gives me last query found.

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import MultiMatch, Match
s = Search(using=client, index=“my_index”).query("multi_match", query="wildcard", cars_model=[“honda_accord”,“honda_crv”, “honda_civic” ])
```

Logically, it should list all the cars model that matches "honda*"

Any help is appreciaited.

Comment: What is the mapping on your index?

Comment: Index maps entire  cars sector that includes other car manufacturers.

Comment: I mean the output of GET http://host:port/myIndex

Comment: You can use `terms` query to search for multiple values on a single field, though take care of the mapping to have as `non-analyzed` since it'll be `analyzed` by default(text fields are `analyzed`)